# Interface variants with generics in c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, abstraction

I am trying to implement a kind of dependency injection / singleton storage for my framework but cannot figure out the last steps because of all the generics and interfaces in the modules.

My infrastructure is composed on a stack of modules:

Base modules:
implement the base controllers and interfaces.
Here I define the repository patterns and interfaces and also the generic base classes for its implementation.

```
public interface IControllerBaseRead<T>
{
    T Get(int Id);
    List<T> GetAll();
    List<T> Find(string sqlCondition, params object[] args);
}



public abstract class ControllerBaseRead<T> : IControllerBaseRead<T> where T : class
{
    public virtual T Get(int id)
    {
        T item = null;
        using (IDataContext context = DataContext.Instance())
        {
            var repository = context.GetRepository<T>();
            item = repository.GetById(id);
        }

        return item;
    }

    public virtual List<T> Find(string sqlCondition, params object[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> items = null;
        using (IDataContext context = DataContext.Instance())
        {
                var repository = context.GetRepository<T>();
                items = repository.Find(sqlCondition, args);
        }
        return items.EmptyIfNull().ToList();
    }
}
```

Now, the second module has a table for employees so I define it's Model and Controller inheriting from the necessary interfaces. Model implements additional interfaces to define some common fields like autit info, IDs,...

```
[TableName("Employee")]
[PrimaryKey("Id", AutoIncrement = true)]
public class Employee : ContentAuditableIdEntity
{
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public int? OrgUnitId { get; set; }
    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}


public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase<Models.Employee>
{
}
```

I have been using this patters for some years now and it's working great as long as I can reference the different modules so they can interact with each other.

Now comes the challenge.

If I want to add some kind of abstraction on the Employee controller, I would create an abstract controller and abstract Model that the HR module could use and implement. So I created a new Module, called abstractions where I add the necessary interfaces:

```
    public interface IEmployee : Interfaces.IContentAuditableIdEntity
{
    int? UserId { get; set; }
    int? OrganizationalUnitId { get; set; }
    int? ManagerId { get; set; }
    int? EmployeeMainRoleId { get; set; }
    string Status { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmployeeController<TModel> : Interfaces.IControllerBase<TModel> where TModel : Models.IEmployee
{ }
```

As a next step I have changed the HR module so the employee module and controller compply with this new interface:

```
    public class Employee : ContentAuditableIdEntity, IEmployee
{
(...)
}


public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase<Models.Employee>, IEmployeeController<Models.Employee>
{
}
```

Now, for the final steps, I have created a singleton class where I can store objects and resolve instances based on their types. The basic methods are as follows. One allows the registration os a callback to that returns a new instance of the given type and the other resolves-it:

```
public DependencyResolverInstance Add<TType>(Func<TType> factory){...}
public TType Resolve<TType>(){...}
```

Now, on the HR module I am trying to create an instance of the employee controller and store it as the abstraction type so it can be used from other modules without having to know or reference the HR module itself:

```
            DependencyResolver.Instance.Add<Abstractions.HR.IEmployeeController<Abstractions.HR.IEmployee>>(() => new Controllers.EmployeeController());
```

I was hoping for this to work because I am creating a new EmployeeController that implements the abstract IEmployeeController with a model that implements IEmployee.
But it is not working because of the following error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Modules.HR.Controllers.EmployeeController' to 'Abstractions.HR.IEmployeeController<Abstractions.HR.IEmployee>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Is there any way of correctly casting the specific instance of the controller to it's abstract Interface definition and keep complying with it's base implementation (base class)?

Thanks!!

**Update**
Just to be clear. My problem is not with DI itself. My problem is on How to convert from EmployeeController to IEmployeeController < IEmployee > .

EmployeeController implements IEmployeeController < Employee > and Employee implements IEmployee, but they are not compatible.

Comment: It is worth noting that this isn't true DI...this is the Service Locator Anti-Pattern and typically is discouraged.

Comment: True, but would it be easier to use true DI in this scenario? From my understanding my problem is hot wo cast to a generic type with an interface as a type from a specific instance that implements those same interfaces.  
Is there a better way to work this indirections?

Comment: I no longer use generic abstractions like this anymore personally. The minimal amount of typing and/or duplicate code it saves isn't worth the tradeoff in true DI and readability, in my opinion. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks @DavidL. How would you approach this abstraction and indirection? Can you point-me to some articles or explain how you would organize the different components used here and how to DI? Many thanks!!